# Folder public/vendor does not get uploaded with cf push

Tags: php, laravel, swisscomdev

I am currently trying to set up a Laravel 5.6 project on Swisscom Application Cloud using the php-buildpack.

Unfortunately, my public/vendor folder does not get uploaded or gets deleted  once uploaded after cf push. If I connect using cf ssh and navigate to the public folder, there is no vendor folder inside. I tried everything including removing everything from .cfignore.

options.json

```
{
  "LIBDIR": "vendor",
  "WEBDIR": "public",
  "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_70_LATEST}",
  "COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR": "vendor",
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "bz2", "zlib", "openssl", "tokenizer", "curl", 
  "mcrypt", "mbstring", "pdo", "pdo_mysql", "fileinfo", "gd", 
  "pdo_sqlite"],
  "PHP_MODULES": ["fpm", "cli"],
  "ADDITIONAL_PREPROCESS_CMDS": [
    "php artisan migrate --force",
    "php artisan config:cache"
  ]
}
```

If I copy my public/vendor folder to public/vendor2, the folder is available on the server after cf push.

Edit: I need to mention that the public/vendor folder is not the folder created by executing composer install but includes all css/html/js files which need to be publicly available. They need to be added locally as some of them need to be built with npm or modified.

Comment: Dont you add that using composer?

Comment: The /vendor folder gets added using composer. But the /public/vendor folder includes publicly accessible files from specific composer packages which are added locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1057) with the PHP buildpack that makes `cf push` ignore all folders with `vendor` as the name.

As a workaround, you could create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), for example, you could use a dir named `my-vendor` and create a symlink to it using `vendor` as the name:

```
$ cd public
$ mkdir my-vendor
$ ln -s my-vendor vendor
```

After deploying `cf push .` you could veryfy via `cf ssh .` and should have the symlink created `public/vendor`, something like this:

```
vcap@aceb5ff2-a9dc-41f4-50be-f234:~/app/public$ ls -al app/public/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 vcap vcap   54 Aug  2 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vcap root 4096 Aug  2 14:13 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap  501 Aug  2 14:01 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap   36 Aug  2 13:50 my-vendor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vcap vcap    9 Aug  2 13:50 vendor -> my-vendor
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there a plan to fix this bug in the near future? Otherwise I will use your workaround.

Comment: I used your workaround and it works like a charm. Thank you!